$(-a)^x$ versus $-(a^x)$ help
$(-2)^3=-8$ and $(-2)^2=4$, right? And $-(2^3)=-8$ and $-(2^2)=-4$.
So that means $(-a)^x$ does not equal $-(a^x)$.
My question is why do we never see graphs of $(-a)^x$ then?? I tried graphing $(-2)^x$ on desmos, but nothing showed up, and my textbook doesn't mention anything about in our exponential chapter so I was really curious. The graph should have negative and positive results right? Is it even a function? I would expect it to be one.

although wait yeah (-a)^1/2 and other even roots wouldn't exist yeah

Welcome to MathSE.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

I found a useful website that visualises (-a)^x with a bit of explanation! Plus you can graph points of the function on desmos with a table to try and make the graph look like the one on the website. Pretty cool. https://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.97/bokinac1.html

Also thank you @N. F. Taussig, I've bookmarked that page now, and thank you for your corrections.

It's perfectly possible to draw a graph of $(-a)^x$ so long as $a$ is negative :).
But I assume you are asking about graphs of $(-a)^x$ where $a$ is a positive real number. Those graphs are not quite as ubiquitous because the expression $(-a)^x$, where $a$ is a positive real number, is only well defined for a relatively small set of values of $x$. Certainly, it is well defined for integer powers of $x$, and it can be well defined for some rational powers (in particular, $x=\frac1q$ where $q$ is an odd number), but for others, in the real numbers, there is no possible definition (i.e., what would be $(-2)^\frac12$?).
When going to the complex numbers, things actually become even worse, because there, all non-integer values of $x$ can yield multiple results ("branches"), and you need to pick one - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm, for example.

Yeah I came to the realisation about even roots a little after posting this, that makes sense. I don't know much about complex numbers but that's really interesting to me!! what a cool but complicated looking wikipedia article. :O
